# Magento2, Customized quote subtotal in cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer

Through observing the event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`, I was able to customize the price of the item in the cart, now I need to have an observer for customizing its subtotal calculation. What event/events need to be observed?

Is it possible to customize the calculation like `$cart->setQuote()->getSubtotal()` in observer and save the quote?

And basically, can it be done through observer or plugin is the solution?

Edit:

Here is my current event:

```
<event name="sales_quote_collect_totals_before">
        <observer name="customuitemprice" instance="vendor\code\Observer\BindUpdateItem"/>
    </event>
```

Observer:

```
class BindUpdateItem implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item)
        {
            $product = $item->getProduct();
            ?How change the subtotal?

        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: `checkout_cart_save_before` Method. Here is the lIst of events https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html Please use Observer http://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-observers-in-magento2/

Comment: @Zinat   Are you able to resolve this requirement? I am also facing a similar requirement. Need to customise the subtotal calculation. It would be helpful if you can post your answer.

Comment: For changes in Subtotal u have to change in following tables `quote`, `quote_item` & `quote_address`

Comment: You can change the price using custom price method like:
$item->setCustomPrice($price);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                $item->save();
and update all totals that you have:
$quote->collectTotals()

Answer (score 1):

You can change the price using custom price method like:

```
$newPrice = '';
$item->setCustomPrice($newPrice);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newPrice);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
$item->save();
```

and update all totals that you have:

```
$quote->collectTotals()
```

It is not a good idea to update only subTotals or grand totals because you will have a lot of problem with the final price calculation

Answer (score 0):

I managed to changed the sub total for any item, here is the code:

```
$item->setCustomRowTotalPrice($item->getCustomPrice() * $item->getQty());
$item->setRowTotal($item->getCustomPrice() * $item->getQty());
$item->setBaseRowTotal($item->getCustomPrice() * $item->getQty());
```

This should be ok. This code couldn't work properly if you are running the function

> calcRowTotal()

which calculate again the sub total for each item in the cart again overwriting your change.

Let me know if you have luck.